# Converting VARCHAR2 to Date and then again convert it to a specific Date format

Tags: sql, oracle, date-conversion

We have an old table where date fields are stored in VARCHAR2 in multiple formats. Now we are planning to:

1) Store these data in a view with proper date fields.

2) Also store these in a single consistent format like MM/DD/YYYY.

Here is what is done for #1: Created a function so that it can parse the VARCHAR2 and convert it into a DATE for different formats like:

```
IF dataTobeConverted IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            IF substr(dataTobeConverted,3,1) = '-'
             THEN retDate:= TO_DATE(dataTobeConverted,'DD-MON-YYYY');
            END IF;

            IF substr(dataTobeConverted,3,1) = '/'
             THEN retDate:= TO_DATE(dataTobeConverted,'MM/DD/YYYY');
            END IF;
        END IF;

RETURN retDate;
```

For #2, we still have to convert these 2  dates above to MM/DD/YYYY, One is already in this format so we need to convert the other one ('DD-MON-YYYY') in first if condition to be stored in MM/DD/YYYY in view's date field. So now we need to convert date to date (from one format to another and return a date)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Store these data in a view

View does not store actual data - it's just a stored `select` statement, nothing more.

> first if condition to be stored in MM/DD/YYYY in view's date field

When you convert a string literal, which represents a date into a value of DATE datatype using specific format, it does not mean that Oracle stores converted value in that format. Providing format mask as a second parameter for `TO_DATE()` function, you just inform oracle to give a value of DATE data type an appropriate internal representation. Date wont be stored in any particular format.
It means, that once you've converted string literal to a value of DATE data type, you just need to use `to_char()` function to display that date in any format you'd like or rely on the date representation format mask set by `nls_date_format`:

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select to_date('21-10-2013', 'dd-mm-yyyy') from dual union all
  3    select to_date('21/10/2013', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
  4    select to_date('21.10.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual
  5  )
  6  select to_char(col, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as res
  7    from t1
  8  ;


RES
----------
21/10/2013
21/10/2013
21/10/2013
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you don't have to convert it again - if you converted a string of characters to be of a `DATE` datatype, then it is stored the same way, no matter how the original date in, for example, `VARCHAR2` datatype, looked like.

The way you present your data to your users depends on the session parameters or model format that you specify using, for example, `TO_CHAR` function. But, internally, a `DATE` is stored without a format model.

Answer (score 0):

As Przemyslaw Kruglej correctly remarks, you should not store dates in a varchar2. This said:

```
alter table oldtable add new_date date;

update oldtable set new_date =
  case
    when substr(old_date,3,1) = '-' then to_date(old_date,'DD-MON-YYYY')
    when substr(old_date,3,1) = '/' then to_date(old_date,'MM/DD/YYYY')
    else null
  end
where old_date is not null;
```

Check if every date was recognized:

```
select * from oldtable where old_date is not null and new_date is null;
```

At last:

```
alter table oldtable drop old_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something like the following:

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET newDateColumn = CASE
                          WHEN substr(oldDateColumn,3,1) = '-'
                            THEN TO_DATE (oldDateColumn, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                          WHEN substr(oldDateColumn,3,1) = '/'
                            THEN TO_DATE (oldDateColumn, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                          WHEN substr(oldDateColumn,3,1) = '.'
                            THEN TO_DATE (oldDateColumn, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
                          ELSE TO_DATE (oldDateColumn)
                       END;
```

This will convert the VARCHAR2 column into DATE column and store the values to the new column, if you have created it already.

Or, in your view, just write the select statement as follows:

```
SELECT ...
       CASE
          WHEN substr(oldDateColumn,3,1) = '-'
            THEN TO_DATE (oldDateColumn, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
          WHEN substr(oldDateColumn,3,1) = '/'
            THEN TO_DATE (oldDateColumn, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
          WHEN substr(oldDateColumn,3,1) = '.'
            THEN TO_DATE (oldDateColumn, 'DD.MM.YYYY')
          ELSE TO_DATE (oldDateColumn)
       END AS column_alias
  FROM ...
 WHERE ...
```

Choose whichever is best for your business requirements, though if I was you, I'd definitely choose the first option of storing the data in a different column and then dropping the old column.